# How to combined duplicate row to one row in laravel 5.7 controller

Tags: laravel

I want to combined the duplicate row to one row and show the result in front end but i face some error please any one help .

```
time_session   | day
------------     ----
1                 saturday
2                 friday
2                 friday
3                 wednessday
```

this is my controller code:

```
 public function classSchedule()
    {
$duplicates = DB::table('applications')
          ->join('batches','applications.time_session' ,'=','batches.id')
          ->select( 'applications.*' , 'batches.*')
         ->groupBy('applications.time_session')
         ->get();
return view('backEnd.classes.manageClass1',['duplicates'=>$duplicates]);}
```

this is my front end code:

```
<td> {{$duplicate->time_session }} </td>

time_session   | day             taking day
------------     ----            ----------
1                 saturday           1
2                 friday             2
3                 wednessday         1

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'pixelmetro.applications.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `applications`.*, `batches`.* from `applications` inner join `batches` on `applications`.`time_session` = `batches`.`id` group by `applications`.`time_session`)
```

Actual out put :
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2317443465016247&set=pcb.442972496253366&type=3&theater&ifg=1

Comment: Do you just want to remove duplicate rows? If so, add ->distinct() before your ->get();

Comment: I don't remove duplicate row  , I just want to count the duplicate row and show FrontEnd  page @Petay87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 1055 error is a MySQL issue that can be resolved changing Laravel config. Go to config/database.php file and change mysql property **strict** from **true** to **false**.  `'strict' => false,`
If you don't want to change it, then you can add a new property **modes**

```
'modes' => [
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
            ]
```

And yeah don't forget to run the command ***php artisan config:cache*** after making changes.

To get desired result you need to use count.

```
$duplicates = DB::table('applications')
          ->join('batches','applications.time_session' ,'=','batches.id')
          ->select( 'applications.*' , 'batches.*', DB::raw('COUNT(applications.time_session) as counter')
         ->groupBy('applications.time_session')
         ->get();
```

In blade:

```
@foreach($duplicates as $duplicate)
 <td>$duplicate->counter</td>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: when config/database.php file and change mysql property strict from true to false. 'strict' => false, then duplicate row doesn't show in front end but insert into database ... simply I want to count the duplicate row and show the number in front end

Comment: This is the solution for sqlstate 1055 error. To get your desired result use count. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have some miss conception on group by.if you group by with a certain column then you have to get others column with aggregate function.
in your case you made group by with (time_session) and you try to get all from the table that's why you got the error.

**solution:** you can make group by with both (time_session and  day) then your problem will be solve.

**sample code:**

```
public function classSchedule()
    {
$duplicates = DB::table('applications')
          ->join('batches','applications.time_session' ,'=','batches.id')
          ->select( 'applications.*' , 'batches.*')
          ->groupBy('applications.time_session')
          ->groupBy('applications.day')
          ->get();
      return view('backEnd.classes.manageClass1',['duplicates'=>$duplicates]);}
```

Comment: the problem not solve ,  now show the " batches" table id number . I want to show which "day" take  users how many times  @Shadiqur

Comment: what you want to show you can specify them on select
like  ->select( 'applications.time_session' ,'applications.day' 'batches.taking_day') Then it will not show the batch_id